# What is the earliest/easiest Summoner weapon to get pets in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I'm interested in trying to play as a Summoner, but at 20 hours in I have found zero items so far that allow me to summon minions.  What is the earliest/easiest summoner weapon to get?  I've looked at the Wiki but am having a hard time telling.  Is it the Slime Staff from the Slime King?  Thanks!

Comment: https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Summon_weapons#Pre-Hardmode Probably some of the ones found here.  But your question is a bit open ended and opinionated.

Comment: @Timmy - it was a bit open ended - I was hoping there was a clear answer I am missing but it doesn't seem like there is.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Pets and summons are different things. Pets do not do damage.

Comment: There is no such item as a "Slime Rod". There is a "Slime Staff", but it is not dropped by the King Slime.

Comment: @OrangeDog - thanks for the info - yes I meant minions not pets, and the Slime Staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Finch Staff](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Finch_Staff) is the easiest summoner weapon to get in Journey Mode, because you start with it.

In other game modes it depends what you mean by "easy". [Abigail's Flower](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Abigail%27s_Flower) only requires that you die, replace the tombstone, and wait. But you might be waiting a while.

The easiest one that doesn't rely on luck is the [Hornet Staff](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Hornet_Staff). Kill the Queen Bee and you're guaranteed enough Bee Wax to craft it.